# Evaluating multiple expressions to determine the range of a numeric variable in php

Tags: php, algorithm

Sorry if the title is confusing.

I have several string expressions in an array like these:

```
var1 <= 6  && var1 > 3
var1 > 2  
var1 > 4.5

var2 < 22.5  
var2 >= 14.25  
var2 < 16
```

How can I go about evaluating all of the expressions to determine:

```
var1 min
var1 max
var2 min
var2 max
```

I understand that with the expressions that are not "or equal to" I won't be able to get an exact value. That is alright.

Comment: Do you have one expression per string, or may one string contain multiple expressions?

Comment: There can be multiple in a string. I updated the original post to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

    $arr = array("var1 <= 6",
    "var1 > 2",
    "var1 > 4.5",

    "var2 < 22.5",
    "var2 >= 14.25", 
    "var2 < 16");

    function find_min_max($arr, $variable) {
        $min = '-inf';
        $max = 'inf';
        while (list($i, $v) = each($arr)) {
            list($var, $rel, $value) = preg_split('/\s+/', $v);
            if ($var != $variable) continue;
            if ($rel == "<" || $rel == "<=") {
                if ($value < $max)
                    $max = $value;
            }
            else if ($rel == ">" || $rel == ">=") {
                if ($value > $min)
                    $min = $value;
            }
        }
        return array($min, $max);
    }
    list($min, $max) = find_min_max($arr, "var1");
    echo "var1 $min - $max \n";
    list($min, $max) = find_min_max($arr, "var2");
    echo "var3 $min - $max \n";
?>
```

Comment: I don't think OP mindes, but it's worth noting this doesn't distinguish `<` from `<=`.

Comment: With the update to the OP one would also need to to split the elements with `"&&"` into different elements. Also if the elements are arbitrary PHP-like expressions, the problem can't be solved.

Comment: I am only using "&&" so this will work. I just have to split them up as you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to do simple linear programming. [SimplexInPHP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplex-in-php/) implements linear programming in PHP, which you could use. See it in action [here](http://gim.altervista.org/ro/immissione_dati_0.php).

The other option is to implement a solution yourself. Use [`split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) to split each inequality into tokens. For each variable, compute the min/max by starting off with the range [-inf, inf] and update it for each inequality. If the operator begins with `<` then update max to `max(cur_max, value)`; otherwise update min to `min(cur_min, value)`.

You'll also have to keep track of whether the end-points are inclusive or exclusive. This can be done with booleans `is_min_inclusive` and `is_max_inclusive`. A new end-point is inclusive if the operator ends in `=`, otherwise it's to exclusive. Be sure to handle the case where you have `x < 1` *and* `x <= 1` (in both orders), which should result in `x < 1`.

Comment: Applying linear programming to inequations with one variable seems like a bit of overkill :)

Comment: @Nikita I agree, but I thought it'd be worth mentioning. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 

$string = "var1 <= 6    &&  var1 > 0 && var2 >= 4 && var2 < 200";
//creates an array with the key 'name' and 'min OR 'max'
function parseExpression($expression){
    $parts = preg_split("|( )+|", $expression,3,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    $result = array('name'=>$parts[0]);
    switch ($parts[1]){
        case '<':
            $parts[2]-=1;
            //NO BREAK <x same as <=(x-1)
        case '<=':
            $result['max'] = $parts[2];
            break;
        case '>':
            $parts[2]+=1;
            //NO BREAK >x same as >=(x+1)
        case '>=':
            $result['min'] = $parts[2];
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception("format not supported");        
    }
    return $result; 
}

$expressions = explode("&&", $string);
$vars = array();
foreach ($expressions as $expression){
    $parsed = parseExpression($expression);
    $name = array_shift($parsed);
    foreach ($parsed as $key => $value){
        if (array_key_exists($key,$vars[$name])){
            switch ($key){
                case 'min':
                    $vars[$name][$key] = min($vars[$name][$key],$value);
                    break;
                case 'max':
                    $vars[$name][$key] = max($vars[$name][$key],$value);
                    break; 
                default:
            }
            throw new Exception("format not supported");
        }
        else{
            $vars[$name][$key] = $value;    
        }
    }
}

var_dump($vars);

?>
```

Comment: I just realized that this is not taking into consideration the most limiting expression, it is just using the last one passed. So if i have this expression: var1 >= 5 && var1 >= 2 It is going to give me var1 min of 2 instead of 5 which is expected.

Comment: @Mike now it is behaving as ou expected it to.

Answer (score 1):

So in your example, you'd expect the minimum var1 to be >4.5 and the max to be <=6?  Have you considered changing your data structure?

If, for example, your data structure looked something like this:

`$limits=array('lte'=>array(6), 'lt'=>array(),'gte'=>array(),'gt'=>(2,4.5);`

then parsing becomes trivial. The max of the gt and gte arrays would be the minimum value, with > or >= depending on which array it came from.  The minimum of lt and lte arrays would be the max value.

Answer (score -1):

I guess...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php

In the example they show nummeric string expressions (so not only casted  floats or ints)

Comment: I give up, I really don't understand what you're trying to do, can't think of a context.